# Image fuzzy in browser, sharp in Photoshop (with NO resizing), why?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, png, resolution, image-quality

I have a `PNG` file that looks fuzzy when I view it in any browser.  However, opening the very same file in Photoshop, making no changes, it looks perfectly sharp.

Why does this PNG look different when there is no difference in the file?  Is there a setting in my browser that could be making the file look fuzzy, or a setting in Photoshop that makes things look sharper than they really are?

I have checked to ensure that I am viewing the image in the browser at the full proper size (it is not being resized by the code).

Totally stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after investigating in different browsers (IE was fuzzy too) and discovering that Chrome was not fuzzy, I decided I had better check on what settings might be affecting how things look in the browser, and was embarrassed to find it was a simple case of my display settings in Windows being set to a larger than 100% size for easier legibility on screen! Returning the settings to normal means the logo displays fine in all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

I really dislike how the browsers do this now, I was having the same problem. My advice, use .svg's for your logos and graphic elements. Problem solved.